# removing columns from a data frame which feature in a list, but don't feature in another list

Tags: r, dataframe

Say, my variable are as follows.

```
df = read.csv('somedataset.csv') #contains 'col1','col2','col3','col4','col5' say
colsSomeRemoveSomeDontRemove = c('col1','col2','col3')
colsDontRemove = 'col2'
```

I would like to remove all those columns from df which feature in **colsSomeRemoveSomeDontRemove**, but are not part of **colsDontRemove**.

So basically, at the end my df should contain only columns `'col2','col4','col5'`

How can I do that?

I have tried doing the following, but could not get it to work

```
df1 = cbind(df[,which(!(names(df) %in% colsSomeRemoveSomeDontRemove))],as.data.frame(df[,colsDontRemove]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[, !(colnames(df) %in% setdiff(colsSomeRemoveSomeDontRemove, colsDontRemove))]
```

Comment: Thanks Ven, just a minor correction. Is it df[, !(colnames(df) %in% setdiff(colsSomeRemoveSomeDontRemove, colsDontRemove))]